# Programacion Java (POO basico: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException)

Tags: java, poo

Copio y pego (me parece mas comodo que una imagen) el codigo.

```
package nueve;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nueve {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    private int arreglo;
    private int AñoEdad=2017;
    private String AlumnoMayorEdad;
    private int Año1, Año2;
    String Nombres [] ;
    int Legajo [] ;
    int AñoNacimiento [];


    public nueve() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Alumnos: ");
        arreglo=sc.nextInt();
        String Nombres [] = new String [arreglo];
        int Legajo [] = new int [arreglo];
        int AñoNacimiento [] = new int [arreglo];
    }


    public void cargardatos() {
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++ ){         
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre de alumno: ");
            Nombres [i] = sc.next();        
            System.out.println("Ingrese el legajo del alumno " + Nombres[i] + ": ");
            Legajo [i] = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese año de nacimiento del alumno " + Nombres[i] + ": ");
            AñoNacimiento [i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    public void CualEsElDeMayorEdad(){
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++){
            if (AñoNacimiento[i]<AñoEdad){
                AlumnoMayorEdad=Nombres[i];
                AñoEdad=AñoNacimiento[i];
            }
        }
    }   
    public String DimeEdad(){
        return "El alumno de mayor edad es: " + AlumnoMayorEdad;
    }
    public void EntreAños(){
        System.out.println("Ingrese los dos años, primero el mayor edad: ");
        Año1=sc.nextInt();
        Año2=sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++){
            if (AñoNacimiento[i]> Año1 && AñoNacimiento[i]<Año2){
                System.out.println("El alumno " + Nombres[i] + " esta entre esos años");
            }
        }
    }
}

package nueve;

public class uso_nueve {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        nueve desempeño = new nueve();

        desempeño.cargardatos();
        desempeño.CualEsElDeMayorEdad();
        desempeño.DimeEdad();
        desempeño.EntreAños();
    }
}
```

**EL PROBLEMA ES CUANDO INGRESO EL NOMBRE DEL PRIMER ALUMNO : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.
TODAVIA NO TENGO CONOCIMIENTOS DE EXCEPCIONES.
PERDON POR LA IGNORANCIA, DEBE SER UNA PAVADA QUE NO ME DOY CUENTA **

ESPERO QUE ME PUEDAN AYUDAR, DEJO LA CONSIGNA QUE ME DEJARON:
Cargar tres vectores que contengan legajo, nombre del alumno y año de nacimiento.
Realizar una consulta por nombre y determinar cuál es el alumno de mayor edad.
Ingresar dos fechas (sólo el año) y mostrar todos los alumnos que nacieron entre esos años.

Comment: No estás mandando llamar la función `nueve()` por ende tus arreglos no tienen longitud alguna, y al querer acceder a `Nombres[i]` te manda error de Puntero Nulo al no existir dicho índice en tu arreglo.

Comment: @Lixus Invoque la funcion nueve() y tampoco.

Comment: ¿Te manda preguntar por el número de alumnos? Si es manda imprimir tus arreglos en consola para ver si los está construyendo con su longitud correctamente. Si no haces `parseInt` a lo que el usuario ingrese como cantidad de alumnos, probablemente tus arreglos no se inicialicen correctamente.

Comment: Si miras el mensaje `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException.` completo verás un "stacktrace" que, entre otras cosas, te dice el número de linea donde ocurrió la exception. Eso es mu util para encontrar el problema.

Comment: Muy bien, la linea de error esta en la linea : Nombres [i] = sc.nextLine();

Comment: Ingreso el numero de alumnos . Pero cuando ingreso el primer nombre esta el problema.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en la inicialización de las variables en el constructor, estas definiendo nuevamente el tipo de dato de cada variable y no es necesario porque ya las definiste antes, al volver a definirlas, esas variables solo están disponibles dentro del constructor, y las variables globales nunca son inicializadas, para solucionar solo debes remover los tipos de datos de las variables.

**Ejemplo:**

```
public nueve() {
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Alumnos: ");
    arreglo=sc.nextInt();
    Nombres = new String [arreglo];
    Legajo = new int [arreglo];
    AñoNacimiento = new int [arreglo];
}
```

Eso debe ser suficiente para que el código funcione.

*Sugerencia hecha un vistazo a las convenciones para escribir código en Java*

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, pude solucionarlo y entenderlo más. Muchísimas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: excelente! happy coding =)

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estas tratando de agregar elementos a un array que no esta inicializado/dimensionado,

```
Nombres [i] = sc.nextLine();
```

si defines los array en el constructor no podras utilizarlos en tu otros metodos de tu programa:

```
 public nueve() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Alumnos: ");
        arreglo=sc.nextInt();
        String Nombres [] = new String [arreglo];
        int Legajo [] = new int [arreglo];
        int AñoNacimiento [] = new int [arreglo];
    }
```

La solucion es usar variables de clase para definir estos array, para poder usarlos en cualquier metodo de tu clase:

```
//String Nombres [] ;
private String[] Nombres;
//int Legajo [] ;
private int[] Legajo;
//int AñoNacimiento [];
private int[] AñoNacimiento;
```

en el constructor entonces, se inicializaran los array que podras usar sin problema en tu programa:

```
public nueve() {
    System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Alumnos: ");
    arreglo=sc.nextInt();
    //String Nombres [] = new String [arreglo];
     Nombres = new String [arreglo];
    //int Legajo [] = new int [arreglo];
     Legajo = new int [arreglo];
    //int AñoNacimiento [] = new int [arreglo];
     AñoNacimiento= new int [arreglo];
}
```

---

Este sería el código :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class nueve {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        nueve desempeño = new nueve();

        desempeño.cargardatos();
        desempeño.CualEsElDeMayorEdad();
        desempeño.DimeEdad();
        desempeño.EntreAños();
    }


    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    private int arreglo;
    private int AñoEdad=2017;
    private String AlumnoMayorEdad;
    private int Año1, Año2;
    private String[] Nombres;
    //int Legajo [] ;
    private int[] Legajo;
    //int AñoNacimiento [];
    private int[] AñoNacimiento;


    public nueve() {
        System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de Alumnos: ");
        arreglo=sc.nextInt();
        //String Nombres [] = new String [arreglo];
         Nombres = new String [arreglo];
        //int Legajo [] = new int [arreglo];
         Legajo = new int [arreglo];
        //int AñoNacimiento [] = new int [arreglo];
         AñoNacimiento= new int [arreglo];
    }


    public void cargardatos() {
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++ ){         
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre de alumno: ");
            Nombres [i] = sc.next();        
            System.out.println("Ingrese el legajo del alumno " + Nombres[i] + ": ");
            Legajo [i] = sc.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingrese año de nacimiento del alumno " + Nombres[i] + ": ");
            AñoNacimiento [i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    public void CualEsElDeMayorEdad(){
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++){
            if (AñoNacimiento[i]<AñoEdad){
                AlumnoMayorEdad=Nombres[i];
                AñoEdad=AñoNacimiento[i];
            }
        }
    }   
    public String DimeEdad(){
        return "El alumno de mayor edad es: " + AlumnoMayorEdad;
    }
    public void EntreAños(){
        System.out.println("Ingrese los dos años, primero el mayor edad: ");
        Año1=sc.nextInt();
        Año2=sc.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i<arreglo; i++){
            if (AñoNacimiento[i]> Año1 && AñoNacimiento[i]<Año2){
                System.out.println("El alumno " + Nombres[i] + " esta entre esos años");
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, pude solucionarlo y entenderlo más. Muchísimas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Excelente Emiliano, saludos!